# Add a CollectionViewController as ChildViewController to a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a view which contains three subview having different view controller (`UICollectionViewController`,`pageviewcontroller` and `uiviewcontroller`).
i am able to add a `uiviewcontroller` but other two controller is not allowed.
I am getting this error.....

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'UICollectionView *__weak' to parameter of type 'UIViewController *'

Is their any way to add these controller to my subview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want to add ViewControllers inside a view, i never need it.
I tried to do that, if can help you this is my running code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) UICollectionViewController  *collectionViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPageViewController        *pageViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController            *simpleViewController;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize collectionViewController;
@synthesize pageViewController;
@synthesize simpleViewController;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewLayout *layout  = [[UICollectionViewLayout alloc] init];
    collectionViewController = [[UICollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    pageViewController       = [[UIPageViewController alloc] init];
    simpleViewController     = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    // Do your stuff with this controllers

    [self.view addSubview:collectionViewController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:pageViewController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:simpleViewController.view];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank You for Your time. actually i was also doing the same but the mistake is was doing is trying to add view controller but not its view. silly mistake....... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You don't add view controllers to views. You add views to views (as subviews) and, much more rarely, controllers to controllers (as child controllers).

Think of them as two parallel hierarchies: Given `ControllerA` that controls view `ViewA`, you want to make `ControllerB` a child controller of `ControllerA` such that it's view, `ViewB` is a subview of `ViewA`.

See the [WWDC 2011 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/): "Implementing UIViewController Containment"